# Usage of SUMIF in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have list of customers and their corresponding revenues in 3 services. These list of customer belongs to various regions- North, East, South, West.
[image]
In above excel, I wish to find sum total region wise. Kindly help to use SUMIF or any other useful function.

Comment: Personally I would always use a PivotTable, instead of SUMIF.  No formulas needed...

Answer (score 0):

In C13 and copied down and across:

```
=SUMIF($A$3:$A$11,$B13,C$3:C$11)
```

provided in A3 and copied down:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,G$3:H$11,2,0)
```

Well done for showing row and column headings but I am surprised (after your 179 As) you don't seem to have realised yet how much less likely an OP is to see a good A quickly when their data sample is presented as an image only.

Answer (score 0):

This array formula seems to work in C13.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C$3:C$11, $B$3:$B$11, IF($H$3:$H$11=$B13, $G$3:$G$11)))
```

Fill right and down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in `C13` copied down and across if required

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($B$3:$B$11,$G$3:$G$11,C$3:C$11)*($H$3:$H$11=$B13))`

`SUMIF` creates a total for all customers but the additional check $H$3:$H$11=$B13 ensures that it only adds those for the relevant zone